# react: uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-deployment

I am trying to get 'state' object in function Application which is out from General class and I am getting this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined". 
  The code is

```
class General extends Comment {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { comments: first_comment};
  }
}

const Application = () => {
  return (
    <div> Hello world beginner: {this.state.comments}</div>
  );
};

render(<Application/>, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Comment: Ask **one** question per question, not three.

Comment: No state in pure functional components. It doesn't even make sense on the face of it; in your `Application` component there's no other reference to state. Did you mean to pass it to `Application` somewhere?

Comment: now I see. I already get the answer but thanks for replaying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application is stateless component. Not to say that arrow functions have lexical scoping of context.

Use props for stateless components.

```
const Application = (props) => {
  return (
    <div> Hello world beginner: {props.comments}</div>
  );
};
```

Or extend React.Component

```
class Application extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
     // init state
  }

  render() {
    return <div> Hello world beginner: {this.state.comments}</div>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Few Things:

*`Stateless Functional Components` don't have `state`, `lifecycle` methods, and `this` keyword.

*You need to connect `General` and `Application` component so that `Application` component can you the `state` value of General `component`.

*Make `Application` component as child of General component and pass the comments value in `props`, and in `Application` access the value by `props.comments`.

Write it like this:

```
class General extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { comments: first_comment};
  }
  render(){
     return (
        <div>
            <Application comments={this.state.comments}/>
        </div>
     )
  }
}

const Application = (props) => {
  return (
    <div> Hello world beginner: {props.comments}</div>
  );
};

render(<General/>, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Check the working example:

```js
class General extends React.Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { comments: 'first_comment'};
      }
      render(){
         return (
            <div>
                <Application comments={this.state.comments}/>
            </div>
         )
      }
    }
    
    const Application = (props) => {
      return (
        <div> Hello world beginner: {props.comments}</div>
      );
    };
    
    ReactDOM.render(<General/>, document.getElementById('container'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='container'/>
```

Comment: I would love but the the first answer was right too. So if I know correct I should choose the first correct answer :(

Answer (score 0):

In your class component you should be extending or subclassing `React.Component` and when you do, that means you are going to be overriding the `constructor()` functions of `React.Component` classes with the one from `General` class-component, but you don't want to do that, you still want to access `React.Component` `constructor()` so you need to pass in `props` to the constructor and to `super()`.

Next, when passing state as props to a functional component, you need to pass in `props` as an argument to the functional component, otherwise when doing this for example:

```
import React from 'react';

const ImageList = () => {
  console.log(props.images);
  return <div>ImageList</div>;
};

export default ImageList;
```

you will get that same error you got. Imagine I am trying to access state from your `General` class-based component into this `ImageList` component above and I do have it imported to `General`, it will give me the same error, because I have not passed `props` as an argument to `ImageList` functional component.